# Django select and order based on related value

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models: `Subscriber` and `Notification`.

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField()

class Notification(models.Model):
    subscriber = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, related_name='notifications')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=TYPES)
```

What I want to retrieve is the subscribers who didn't receive a notification (based on `type`) within the last 5 minutes and order them by the time they last received ascending.

I would probably solve this within sql with a subquery or something but I'm wondering if it's doable in Django.

Here's a working SQL query that does what I need:

```
SELECT
    s.* 
FROM
    subscribers s 
    LEFT JOIN
        notifications n 
        ON( n.subscriber_id = s.id ) 
WHERE
    (
( NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT
                NULL 
            FROM
                notifications nn 
            WHERE
                nn.subscriber_id = s.id
        )
        OR 
        (
            n.type = 1 
            AND n.timestamp < Curdate() - INTERVAL 5 minute 
        )
) 
    )
ORDER BY
    pu.timestamp ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `exclude` queryset method to exclude subscribers who *have* received a notification and then annotate the queryset with the last notification received to give the order.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import Max

five_minutes_ago = timezone.now() - timedelta(minutes=5)
Subscriber.objects.exclude(
    notifications__type='notification_type_x',
    notifications__time__gt=five_minutes_ago
    )
    .annotate(last_notification=Max('notifications__time'))
    .order_by('last_notification')
```